# How to include static script files in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, script-tag

My client has a requirement regarding the static javascript files that are included in `index.html` of my react project.
He wants these static js file to be imported in specific react component where they are required instead globally.
How can I achieve this ?
And is it a good practice to import static js file at component level ?

Comment: are these static files present in your project ? If this is the case you can add `import './static-file.js'` at the begining of your component file

Comment: Yes, the static files are present in my project. But the files are outside `src` folder so react won't allow to import them. Neither I want to change my project's folder structure.